# Putting data from a database into highcharts using $.getJSON

Tags: highcharts

I'm having some problems with $.getJSON, I really need some help because I don't know how to solve the problem and I've been stuck here for days. This is the js file that should generate highcharts when selecting a select option in HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#paese").change(function(){
  var seriesOptions = [];
$.getJSON("prova.php", function(data) {
    seriesOptions = data;
});
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
   renderTo: 'container',
   type: 'column',
   spacingLeft: 20,
   borderWidth: 1
},
....
series: [{
   name: 'Italia',
   data: seriesOptions
}],
```

Is there anything wrong in the first part? When I select an option, it seems like highcharts don't get the php file, but I'm pretty sure it's correct, here it is(PHP file):

```
<?PHP 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
$paese = null;
if(isset($_GET['paese'])) $paese = $_GET['paese'];
$ok = mysql_select_db("liberta", $conn);
$response = array();
$sql="SELECT `valori`.Punteggio FROM `valori` INNER JOIN `nazioni` ON `valori`.Nazione
= `nazioni`.ID WHERE `nazioni`.Nome = '$paese'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($record=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
$response[] = intval("$record[0]");
}
mysql_close($conn);
print(json_encode($response));
```

I'm trying to get the data from a database I created with PHPmyadmin and put them directly into highcharts, but it doesn't work. I'd be very pleased if you could help me, also because this is is an exam I have to sit. Thank you very much.

Comment: How your data looks like, which you get ? $.getJSON("prova.php", function(data) {
    seriesOptions = data;
});

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familair with article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing.

You need to have strucuture like:

```
{
     data:[1,2,3]
}
```

Try to replace

```
while($record=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
      $response[] = intval("$record[0]");
}
```

with

```
while($record=mysql_fetch_row($res)){
      $response['data'][] = intval($record[0]);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do like that, but it doesn't work yet. The data I get from php are a simple array: [1,2,3,4,...]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the javascript part. When you call $.getJSON, the callback you provide will be called asynchronously when the server responds. Howether in your code you are calling the Highcharts() constructor immediately in a synchronous way. At the point its called the seriesOption variable still equals to []. Try calling the constructor from the callback like this:

```
$.getJSON("prova.php", function(data) {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(....
           series: [{
              name: 'Italia',
              data: data}])});
```

Comment: I tried to do like that, but it doesn't work yet. The data I get from php are a simple array: [1,2,3...]